# Python count rows with a special values

Tags: python, dataframe, counting

my dataframe looks like this:

df1:

| ident | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 |  | 4 |  |  |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |  | 3 |
| 6 |  | 3 | 2 |  |
| 7 |  |  | 3 |  |
| 8 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 9 | 1 |  |  |  |

Now i need something like a analysis from that df.
It should look like:

df2:

| name | just_name_sum |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0 |

the column just_name_sum count the columns from df1 where there are no other entry in the other columns exept the ident column.
How can i count something like this?

thx

Comment: High level this is what I'd do: From `df1` first drop every _line_ that has more than 1 entry that's not NA. (NA = not available). Then in the resulting `df`, for each colum just sum up how many non-NA values there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this via a simple `for` loop:

```
summation = dict()
df_temp = df.drop('ident', axis=1)
for col in df_temp.columns:
    summation[col] = df_temp.loc[:,df_temp.columns!=col].isna().all(axis =1).sum()
pd.DataFrame([summation]).transpose()
```

output:

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0 |

List comprehension version: (If you're a fan)

```
pd.DataFrame([{col: df_temp.loc[:,df_temp.columns!=col].isna().all(axis =1).sum()
              for col in df_temp.columns}]).transpose()
```